# NodeJs And Express Folder Structure

Tags: node.js

am having a lot of trouble shifting from java and php to javascript and nodejs in general. I googled ( after reading so many books and watching tutorials) how to populate a mongodb database using mongoose, from a web form. I put all the code to get data from form fields and populate db in app.js. Now i want to separate the code to handle the various forms i have in my website, into individual files. Like i have 3 forms to register a doctor, patient and a receptionist, and since they all give different information to sign up, i want to have 3 individual files to handle them and put them into individual collections in mongodb. Now, where do i store these 3 files, and how do i connect them to app.js? or in general what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating REST API with different URLs using express. This link can help you with that. [creating REST APIs with express](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters)

once you have different APIs each handling a user form, you can process the form contents using the req reference in the callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Nevertheless, I still dont have that clear image of what goes on in Node. At least not in the way i know Java or PHP. What exactly goes on in Node? Coz am really getting frustrated that after copying/reading code on one solution, i can't solve another problem independently. I want to have a high level view (map) of how Node and Express and Mongodb works. What advice do you have? Or what did you do to understand Node in you fingertips? Thanks in advance,,

Comment: I am also a beginner. Its very important to understand the javascript basics like callbacks, promises, hoisting, closure etc. Start with building simple apps with node.js , since i was used to the synchronous execution flow, it was a bit confusing to think in async and non blocking execution. Apart from the above , rest are pretty easy. Doesn't matter if its mongo or mysql, everything has node.js client to handle crud operations.Good luck!